# Null Reference Exception - while using Selenium Web Driver for Automated testing

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I can enter username,password in the Login page and can navigate to the next page; after that i am trying to click on a button using XPATH during when am getting Null Reference Exception.

The reason based on my research for this exception is that the web driver is pointing to the login(previous) page and so can't find the required element(button) in this(current) page to click.

I know there is an inbuilt method switchTo to make the driver point to this page but i don't know how to use it. I tried a few methods by searching in google but all of them have failed.

how to use switchTo method to make the driver point to current page?

Comment: I have no clue what you mean, I used selenium and I truly don't. And without code and just you explaining your research we won't be able to help you

Comment: i want to set the focus of the driver to the current window that has popped up. When i click on login button am taken to a new URL right?  i want to set the focus of web driver to that new (current) URL. do you get it now? There's not much code involved here to share.

Comment: Selenium should open the browser and navigate itself, then it will keep track of everything (like current page) itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below line of code is used to make the driver switch to the current window that is open.

SPCCommonValues.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(SPCCommonValues.Driver.WindowHandles.Last());

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to find and implementation of the interface shown in the code snippet below.
Depending on the target browser, you could choose a driver, include that in your solution as a nuget package, and in the package, there should usually be a class implementing this interface. A sample driver nuget package is Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver

```
namespace OpenQA.Selenium
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Defines an interface allowing the user to access the browser's history and to
    //     navigate to a given URL.
    public interface INavigation
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Move back a single entry in the browser's history.
        void Back();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Move a single "item" forward in the browser's history.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     Does nothing if we are on the latest page viewed.
        void Forward();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Load a new web page in the current browser window.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   url:
        //     The URL to load. It is best to use a fully qualified URL
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     Calling the OpenQA.Selenium.INavigation.GoToUrl(System.String) method will load
        //     a new web page in the current browser window. This is done using an HTTP GET
        //     operation, and the method will block until the load is complete. This will follow
        //     redirects issued either by the server or as a meta-redirect from within the returned
        //     HTML. Should a meta-redirect "rest" for any duration of time, it is best to wait
        //     until this timeout is over, since should the underlying page change while your
        //     test is executing the results of future calls against this interface will be
        //     against the freshly loaded page.
        void GoToUrl(string url);

        void GoToUrl(Uri url);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Refreshes the current page.
        void Refresh();
    }
}
```